# how to enable the functions after the ClientInstanceName dot will show the function that we write in js file without use casting

Tags: asp.net

```
ASPxClientSpinEdit.prototype.NewMethod = function () { alert("MyMethod"); }
var a = ASPxClientSpinEdit.Cast(s);
           a.NewMethod();
```

How if I don't want to use `ASPxClientSpinEdit.Cast();`